# How to remove numbers in a string but keep the spaces in postgresql?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

So I have a column with the following values that some times has a number in the beginning

```
turtle boat
10 banana split
lord Thanos
23 macbook
```

How to query to remove numbers and the space in front of the numbers, but not the space in the middle of the string?

**Intended output:**

```
turtle boat
banana split
lord Thanos
macbook
```

Query I tried from another question in here:

```
select regexp_replace(mycolumn, '[^[:alpha:]]', '', 'g')
```

Problem with this query is that it completely removes all spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will remove the leading digits and the space:

```
select regexp_replace('10 banana split', '^\d+ ', '');

/^\d+[ ]/
 ^ asserts position at start of a line
  \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
    + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
     [ ] matches the character ' ' literally (case sensitive)
```

The `g` modifier, for 'global', is why in your regex all spaces were removed, as matched as non-alpha characters.

fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/20841/3)

Comment: i like stripping the leading number better than stripping the leading not alpha (and not space).   either works.  addressing the number seems more appropriate because the op wanted to remove a potential leading number.

Answer (score 9):

You can exclude all characters except of letters and spaces. Additionally, use `trim()` to remove leading or trailing spaces:

```
with my_data(mycolumn) as (
values
    ('turtle boat'),
    ('10 banana split'),
    ('lord Thanos'),
    ('23 macbook')
)

select trim(regexp_replace(mycolumn, '[^[:alpha:]\s]', '', 'g'))
from my_data

    btrim     
--------------
 turtle boat
 banana split
 lord Thanos
 macbook
(4 rows)
```